# Streamwriter and Streamreader

Tags: c#-4.0

I have my uni assignment and it's only very basic coding but I have to do

A user shall be able to store records to a file. On start-up a user shall be able to select a file of records and load these into the program.

I am having trouble with this as it will save but once I close the program and re-open it they are gone, any ones help is appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SaveToFile(records, file);
}

private void SaveToFile(List<Client> records, string file)
{

    //File.WriteAllText(file, String.Empty);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);

    try
    {
        AddMember();

        for (int i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(records[i].WriteToFile());
        }

        writer.Close();
    }
    catch (IOException z)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + z);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You don't need `StreamReader` in your `SaveToFile` method (unless you're also reading from the file).  2.  Sounds like you might be overwriting the file - try using `StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file, true);` - the second parameter will append new data to the file.

Comment: Also, can you post the code for `Client`?  I'm curious as to what you are doing in the `WriteToFile()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Before closing the StreamWriter you should call Flush() method. Flush() Clears all buffers for the current writer and causes any buffered data to be written to the underlying stream.

Comment: Calling `Close()` also flushes the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

```
reader.clos();
```

you forgot this

Comment: Yes, OP should close the reader (actually, it doesn't even need to be in the save method), but this will not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but it sounds like you might be overwriting the file when you start the program.

In your `SaveToFile` method, you have the following two lines at the start:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
```

The first one will create a new file with the name in `file`.  The second one isn't needed if you're not doing any reading from the file.

Now, if you have a similar block of code in somewhere else in your program that is executed before the `SaveToFile` method is called, it will overwrite the file (and since you most likely don't write anything in that earlier part of the code, you're left with a blank file).

To prevent this, there are two suggestions I'll offer:

1. Only create a `StreamWriter` when you are going to be writing to the file.  Any other times you create a `StreamWriter`, you will be overwriting the existing file.
2. If you don't want to overwrite the file, you can use the overload of the constructor that takes a second parameter (a boolean) to indicate whether or not to append new data to the file:

   StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file, true);

Additionally, I'd suggest getting to know and use `using` blocks, as this will take care of closing and flushing the `StreamWriter` (and its underlying stream) for you, even if an exception occurs and is unhandled:

```
private void SaveToFile(List<Client> records, string file)
{

    try
    {
        AddMember();

        // If you don't want to append but overwrite, use:
        // using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file, append))
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(records[i].WriteToFile());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException z)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + z);
    }
}
```